# Vuejs - Show pages/Vue files with a different router than vue-router (Backbone router)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, webpack, vue.js

I have a backbone router and I decided that I want to use Vuejs for rendering, but not sure how to achieve this.

For now, on each route, I used the require method to get the `.vue` file with the `<template>` and the `<script>` and send that to the render method, but this looks and feels crazy and I wonder if there is an official way or some resources.

```
//Backbone router structure
var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "home",
        "about": "about",
        "contact":"contact"
    },

    home: function(){
        bin.log('Mounted Home');


    },
    about: function(){
        bin.log('Mounted About');


    },
    contact: function(){
        bin.log('Mounted Contact');
    }

});
```

---

```
var currentRoutePage = require('vues/page' + routeName + '.vue');

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    render: function (createElement) {
        return createElement(currentRoutePage);
    }
});
```

Here is a bin where you can play with it: http://www.webpackbin.com/4yGbxwd8f

Comment: Why don't you use the official vue-router? https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router

Comment: @Phil This is a legacy app, that already has this backbone router. I know about vue router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fount the answer here, unfortunately, the webpackbin.com service has some issue and I cannot make this work online, but it work on my local setup:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/routing.html